# Android Emulator is incompatible with Hype-V

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v

Tried to Launch Android Emulator in the studio, but it ended up with Hyper-V error inside my virtual machine. Tried different solutions from Stackoverflow. But none of them helped. Did anyone successfully launched the emulator in a VM ?

[image]

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same error on my Win10 PC, not a VM.

Comment: As per our team, Emulator is Virtual and cannot install it in a VM. So, we installed it in non-VM environment and it was successful.